# Is it possible to have a link inside a textbox like Outlook (names of the recipients)

Tags: html

Would this work?

```
<input type="text" value="<a href=jroq@gmail.com>JROQ</a>"></input>
```

How could I make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. **Yes**, because the value attribute can accept any string (although you really should use HTML entities for the `<` and `>` characters) so you could pass that string to the recipient of the form submission. **No**, because if you are trying to make an actual hyperlink that is not valid HTML.

It also begs the question: *why would you put a hyperlink in an input field?* If you're trying to send an email from your webpage there are plenty of ways to do it. You can:

1. Use `mailto:` in the hyperlink to call the default email program on the user's computer to sent the email: `<a href="mailto:jroq@gmail.com">JROQ</a>`
2. Use a `<form>` to capture the form information and then send it to a server side script written in the language of your choice so it can send the email for you.
3. Set the `action` attribute of the `<form>` element to be the email address you wish to send the email to:  `<form action="mailto:jroq@gmail.com">` (be prepared for ugly emails, though)

Comment: Good sir, the reason why I want to do this is to implement it in a messaging service. 
I would want to do it like this:
http://support.gfi.com/manuals/en/faxmaker/fax14user/images/Outlook%20Send%20message%20dialog%20with%20Microsoft%20Word%20attachment.png

See the "To:" part? Now I would do it in Javascript and PHP, get the strings in the textbox separated by a ';' then parsing it and checking the names against the emails in the database but it would result in duplicate values if there are two names alike. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: Would this work, what if I use parallel arrays and add to the first one the name then on the other one the email, then if I will send the message I'll use the array of emails? That way all I need to edit is text. To give you a great example of what I'm trying to achieve, here in StackExchange if you post a new question, the tags textbox does what I want to do. How will I do that?

Comment: If you're trying to make a web page that looks like that screenshot and sends emails then there isn't a whole lot to it. You would use a regular HTML form to capture the email information (recipients, subject, message, etc) and then use whatever server side programming language you prefer to process it. I can't explain the details of how to do the programming as it is beyond the scope of this website. But if you need help coding you can ask at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Just be sure to show what work you've done and ask specific questions or else your questions will be closed.

Comment: Thanks good sir, but I would have thought all web questions go here. Once again, thank you! ^^

Comment: Programming specific questions belong at StackOverflow and more general website operation questions belong here. There is some overlap but that's basically how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script language="javascript">
function Reload() {
window.location.reload();
}
function NewWindow(mypage, myname, w, h, scroll, statusbar, tool, menu, location) {
var winl = (screen.width - w) / 2;
var wint = (screen.height - h) / 2;
winprops = 'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+wint+',left='+winl +',scrollbars='+scroll+', status='+statusbar+',toolbar='+tool+', menubar='+menu+', location='+location+',resizable=no';
win = window.open(mypage, myname, winprops);
if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 4) {
win.window.focus();
}
}
</script>
<script language="javascript">
function Close()
{
self.close();
if (opener && !opener.closed)
{
opener.Reload();
}
}
</script>
<body>
<input type="text" style="cursor:pointer;color:blue;text-decoration:underline;" name="orgurl" size="30" tabindex="2" value="http://url" onClick="javascript:NewWindow(this.value,'name','1100','900','yes','yes','yes','yes', 'yes')">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this code may demonstrate a solution to the problem, a code only answer is not high quality.   Could you also explain the approach?  What are you trying to accomplish?   Why is this code needed?